# Is it possible to dynamically call an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

Let's say I have a model `Person` with an arbitrary number of attributes, including `name`. Is it possible to dynamically select which attribute to call by specifying it with a variable? Something like this:

```
person.name = "Jake"
attr = "name"
puts person.attr
=> "Jake"
```

I could do this with a conditional statement like this:

```
if attr == "name"
  puts person.name
elsif attr == "height"
  puts person.height
  ...
```

but this seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using ActiveRecord, you can use `[]` to get an attribute.

```
person = Person.last
attr = "height"
puts person[attr]
```

But this will only work for attributes in `Person.columns_hash` and won't work for things like associations.

For that, you'll want to use `public_send`, like,

```
person = Person.last
attr = 'height'
puts person.public_send(attr.to_sym)
```

If you're going to allow a user to select what attribute this is, you'll want to whitelist so someone doesn't `attr = params[:attribute]` and call `?attribute=destroy` and destroy a record. Unless you want them to... :)

Comment: I think there is a typo in you second larger code block. You probably mean `puts person.public_send(attr.to_sym)` since attr stores the `'height'` string :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `person.send(:height)`. It opens up a whole new world of meta-programming, huh?

Comment: No metaprogramming here, none at all :) And better to use `public_send` to prevent oneself from unintentionally using another class' private parts.

Comment: @Phlip I suppose it should be `person.send(attr)`.

Comment: But should it be `person.public_send(attr.to_sym)`?

Comment: @Phlip: no need for symbolizing. Strings work just as well.

Comment: Ruby is going to symbolize it internally with `intern` on the C side, so being a symbol doesn't hurt anything, so it would be more efficient as a symbol if the same name is used more than once anywhere, or already used anywhere in the Ruby VM.